Does the IRR always exist?
For a project or an investment I saw the IRR was the rate making the NVP equal to zero (although I guess there could be two such rates). Does it always make sense to talk about the IRR ? In particular can we always make the NVP equal 0 ?
Let's say that I invest 1 million in a project, I make 2 millions year 1 and lose 1.5 millions year 2. I believe we would need to find real roots of the polynomial -x^2+2x-1.5, but it has none. So do we require something more on the NPV in order to be able to talk about this root or am I falling into some trap ?

Firstly, your algebra is wrong since you're discounting the cash flow backwards(it should be -1 + 2x - 1.5x^2) as Chris also points out, but I believe that answer is wrong also.
There would be 3 cash flows: the initial investment, the 2MM earned after year one, and the 1.5MM lost in year two (I'm ignoring residual value of any assets bought since you did not mention it). So the IRR would be the value of r that satisfies the equation
0 = -1 + 2/(1+r) - 1.5/(1+r)^2

Unfortunately there is no r that satisfies the equation, since the undiscounted total is negative, and discounting the final cash flow more than the second would only make it worse.  Either an additional positive cash flow or some residual value would be needed to make the undiscounted NPV positive.
So yes, sometimes the IRR cannot be calculated. IRR is essentially "at what interest rate could I invest/borrow funds to get the exact same present value of all cash flows".  Typically you need a combination of positive and negative cash flows to compute an IRR, but even then, there are cases where there is not a "rate" at which you get a zero NPV.
A trivial case: say I drop two $20 bills on the ground, one blows away, and I pick up the other one. My cash flows are then -40 and +20; there is no "rate" at which I can discount these cash flows to get a zero NPV.
You might also find that there are _multiple IRRs that solve the equation, though typically you end up with many possible IRRs that are nonsensical (e.g. negative or extremely large).
In these cases you need to look at other measures - possibly the NPV with a fixed discount rate, or "payback period" where you calculate how long it takes to get your initial investment back. Both can be viable alternatives to IRR.

Your IRR: -1 + 2/(1 + r) - 1.5/(1 + r)^2 = 0 appears to say invest 1m i.e. -1 then next year withdraw 2m i.e. +2 then the following year, in order to close-out the investment and make NPV = 0 a further investment of 1.5m i.e. -1.5 is required. So not surprising there is no solution for r.

Correct - with a net negative total it's usually impossible to discount cash flows and obtain a zero NPV. It is possible in some cases (e.g. if the loss is very far out relative to the gain) but in this case it's not.

The IRR is useful for accounting for multiple cash flows, i.e. Wikipedia: IRR

There are only 2 cash flows in the case below: 1m in & 1.5m out.

Let's say that I invest 1 million in a project, I make 2 millions year 1 and lose 1.5 millions year 2.

The case could be set up as an IRR, i.e.

solve for r
r = 0.224745

But it would be simpler to calculate directly


Yes indeed, this example doesn't work. However, we could consider -x^2+2x-1.5 and deduce from it a scenario where the NVP is never zero. Therefore, the question is still standing.

Why are you ignoring the second cash flow?

@DStanley A gain and a loss on the initial investment aren't cash flows. There is only 1m gaining 200%, then losing 50%, i.e. time-weighted return, 1m grows to 3m, then 3m shrinks to 1.5m : (3/1 * 1.5/3)^(1/2) - 1 = 22.4745% p.a. So the first cash flow is the initial 1m investment, and the 2nd cash flow is the imagined withdrawal of the remaining 1.5m which is left at the end, (not the 50% loss, which is also 1.5m but not a cash flow).

Okay I see you're interpreting it as unrealized gains like buying a stock. I was interpreting it more like a project - you invest 1MM (cash outflow). the project makes 2MM (cash inflow) then loses 1.5MM (cash outflow).
